# Set certain amount of pixels to 1 inside of a polygon (GRASS)

Tags: raster, grass-gis, vector, r, random

I have a rather coarse vector map with polygons and want to calculate a (sufficiently) finer raster map defined by spatial extension and resolution. Every polygon of the vector map has a value associated that describes the percentage of pixels of the finer map inside the polygon that should be randomly set to 1. The fraction of pixels set to 1 should be as exact as possible.

Example: Polygon 7 is associated with a value of 20%. 50 pixels of the finer map would be (mainly) situated inside Polygon 7. Thus, 50*0.2=10 out of the 50 should be set to 1.

As a possible approach in GRASS, I found `v.to.rast` with `use=cat` to create a raster map from the polygons where the value indicates in which polygon they lie. Now, I would need to select randomly a percentage of the pixels with the same value.

Comment: Do you need *exactly* that percentage of pixels selected within each polygon or do you want to select each pixel independently with the given probability? The latter is much easier to do--and corresponds to many common random sampling procedures--but will typically select a slightly different number than actually targeted.

Comment: @whuber I'm looking for the exact solution (as far as possible with integer number of pixels).

Comment: Maybe better asked on the user list: http://grass.osgeo.org/support/mailing-lists/ since way more people are reading there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in conjunction with R. First, as assumed in the question, `v.to.rast` with `use=cat` is used to find the pixels of the finer raster map that lie in each polygon. Subsequently, R is used to set the correct amount of pixels to 1.

The following scripts have to be adopted to the specific needs. In the driving GRASS script, `irr` is the vector map of polygons. Its connected database has the column `cat`, which identifies each polygon uniquely, and the column `IRRI_PCT` that gives the percentage of fine pixels that should be set to 1.

Main GRASS script:

```
# target region and resolution
g.region n=2.4 s=-2.6 w=-2.6 e=3.8 nsres=0.01 ewres=0.01
# find pixels of target map which lie in each polygon of irr
v.to.rast --o in=irr out=irr_rast use=cat

# run R
R CMD BATCH apply_irr.R
```

R script:

```
library(spgrass6)
rast <- readRAST6("irr_rast")        # raster with values to use with
                                     # one irrigation fraction
irrrast <- rast                      # target map
irrrast$irr_rast <- 0.               # initialize it

## read table of irrigation fraction
temp_irr <- execGRASS("db.select", parameters=list(table="irr"), intern=TRUE)
temp_con <- textConnection(temp_irr)
irrtab <- read.table(temp_con, header=TRUE, sep="|")
close(temp_con)

## set irrtab$IRRI_PCT % pixels to 1
for (nr in 1:nrow(irrtab)) {
  pixels <- which(rast$irr_rast==irrtab$cat[nr])
  irrrast$irr_rast[sample(pixels, floor(length(pixels)*irrtab$IRRI_PCT[nr]/100.)  )] <- 1.
}

## write results
writeRAST6(irrrast, "irr_rast", overwrite=TRUE)
```

The final raster map is available in GRASS with the name `irr_rast`.